# How do I make \uXXXX appear in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do I let my Eclipse use \uXXXX symbols?

Should I change the font?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I meant I want it to display it. i.e    System.out.print("\uXXXX");  .

Comment: Importantly, *display it in the console*. What happens when you try at the moment?

Comment: I get a ?. No matter what numbers I put in for XXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will never use \u escapes for display in the console window. That's just not in its repertoire.

However, that's probably not what you want.

If you have coded some Java with a \u escape in the source, your first problem is to configure the run / debug configuration to use an appropriate encoding for the console window. UTF-8 is usually the right answer. Then, you need to select an appropriate font in the eclipse preferences for the particular character you've chosen. However, whatever you do, "\uxxxx" will never be what comes *out*. What you will get is the character specified by your unicode escape.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with another compiler? i.e Textpad

Comment: textpad isn't a compiler. I have no idea what you actually want to do here.

Comment: Sorry. I'm doing an assignment for a class I have. I need to put text inside of a "box". Only using System.out.println("") and System.out.print(""); . I was wondering if their is a program I can use to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to see unicode output in the console, make sure the font you're using supports unicode and that the output encoding is set to UTF-8.

When running this in my pretty vanilla install of Eclipse:

```
System.out.println("\u0CA0_\u0CA0");
```

I get this as expected in the Eclipse console output:

```
ಠ_ಠ
```

Comment: I get ?_? for some reason. How do I set the font to support unicode and how do I set the output to UTF-8?                                                      I would be extremely happy if you could reply.

Comment: Usually question marks imply an invalid encoding. Try setting the text file encoding in `Preferences > Workspace` to `UTF-8`.  If that doesn't work, open up the run configuration, go to the `Common` tab, and set the Encoding to `UTF-8`